# Merge XFDF with PDF file to create annotated PDF version in web system

Tags: java, pdf, itext, xfdf

I have created an iPad apps that can draw PDF annotations. And the annotation data will be exported to XFDF format and store in my web system (implemented by Java and Spring).

Now I want to merge XFDF to an existing PDF file and generate an annotated PDF version when my users view the PDF in the web system. So that they can see the annotations they have drawn in the iPad apps.

So my question is how to merge the XFDF to PDF and create a new PDF file for users to view in my web system.

I have studied some libraries like iText. It seems I have to parse the XFDF and draw the annotations one by one programmatically. Any other suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Currently, merging annotations from XFDF into PDF isn't supported in iText. I've put it on our road map a couple of times, but somehow it always fell off the list, because there was no customer demand for it (only user demand). Maybe I'll implement this as a hobby project. If you want to put it higher on the priority list, please create a ticket on the ticketing system for paying customers.

Comment: Thanks Bruno. Besides, I found that the current XFDFParser does not parse the annotation information. If I have implemented the parser, I should have enough data to create PdfAnnotation class from the iText Library and create a new PDF right?